# Vuetify - Handle multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have multiple checkboxes and I want to keep track of the selected values, but for some reason, after I uncheck a checkbox its label gets removed, and then re-added as `true` or `false`.

How to correctly keep track of selected values in checkboxes with vuetify?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      names: ['John', 'Jacob', 'Jules'],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-checkbox v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="name" v-model="names[index]" :label="name">
      </v-checkbox>
    </v-container>
    Selected names: {{names}}
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of objects with separate fields for label and checkbox value as below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      names: [
        {value: 'John', selected: true},
        {value: 'Jacob', selected: false},
        {value: 'Jules', selected: true}
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-checkbox v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="index" v-model="name.selected" :label="name.value">
      </v-checkbox>
    </v-container>
    Selected names: <pre> {{names}} </pre>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you'd like to retain the same array structure, you could do this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      names: ['John', 'Jacob', 'Jules'],
      selectedNames: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleCheckboxClicks(name) {
      this.selectedNames.includes(name) ?
        this.selectedNames = this.selectedNames.filter(n => n != name) :
        this.selectedNames.push(name)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app style="margin-bottom: 10rem">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-checkbox v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="name" @click="handleCheckboxClicks(name)" :label="name">
      </v-checkbox>
    </v-container>
    Selected names: {{selectedNames}}
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't handle duplicate names, so @AnuragSrivastava's answer is still a better way go.